# PHP if $_SERVER('REQUEST_URI') is empty, or only contains $_GET

Tags: php

How can I check if the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is empty (i.e. user visited `domain.com/`), but leave an exception for if there is a `$_GET` in the URL (`domain.com/?a=1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parse_url` to achieve this

```
if(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_QUERY) !== null)
{
    // It Contains get
    var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

Comment: I just realized can't i do `if (request_URI is not empty){if ($_GET) {..}}`

Comment: @iight did not want to use anything relating to `$_GET` because the `REQUEST_URI` might also bee from Database and you would want a solution that would work weather via get or via link